# No Main Manifest Attribute, IntelliJ

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, jar, manifest

I Have been having this issue for a while and today finally solved it.

When creating a Jar artifact in IntelliJ and trying to run it, I always got the error

> no main manifest attribute, in xxxx.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ONLY occured when I added library files to the artifact, and without external libraries the jar executed fine.

The process I followed to create the artifact was as follows :
File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> add Jar -> from modules with dependencies... -> After The Next Windows the following was shown [image]

And my problem was fixed when I removed all the items that had 'Extracted" prefixes. I also added The Library File to look like this -> Which made my jar with library dependencies work again[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJEoe.png)